# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "category" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've deleted this `field` from my `Post` model, but it's still bringing up this error when create make a `Post` instance:

```
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/james/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/james/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/james/app/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "category" violates not-null constraint
```

When I removed `category` from my `Post` model and performed `makemigrations` & `migrate`, it succesfully generated this file in my `migrations` folder:

**0002_remove_post_category**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.8 on 2018-03-16 22:56
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('post', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='post',
            name='category',
        ),
    ]
```

so It shouldn't be causing problems any more, but it still is.

Any idea why?

Comment: did you receive a sucessfull message when you ran migrate?

Comment: No I think it said `No migrations to apply`

Comment: did you fake any migration?

Comment: No I simple deleted `category = models.Charfield()` from the model and performed `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: what does `python manage.py showmigrations` show to you?

Comment: `python manage.py showmigrations` shows the migration: post: `[X] 0002_remove_post_category`

Comment: try to revert migrations to zero, (`python manage.py migrate app_name zero`) then run `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Comment: Wouldn't that delete everything in the database?

Comment: Did you fixed it  ?